# Why got the 2 items when Using the reduce operator in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I tried to do a test to get the Kafka record with the minimum field Frequency by the following code, however finally I got two records instead of one record with minimum field Frequency.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment().setParallelism(1);
    env.getConfig().disableSysoutLogging();

    env.getConfig().setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(4, 10000));
    env.enableCheckpointing(5000); // create a checkpoint every 5 seconds
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(parameterTool); // make parameters available in the web interface
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Tuple1<Integer>>> input = env
            .addSource(
                    new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(
                            parameterTool.getRequired("input-topic"),
                            new KafkaEventSchema(),
                            parameterTool.getProperties())
                            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new CustomWatermarkExtractor()))
            .keyBy("word")
           .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10)))
            .reduce(new MyReduceFunction(), new MyWindowFunction());
    input.print()
    ;

    env.execute("Kafka 0.10 Example");
}

private static class MyReduceFunction implements ReduceFunction<KafkaEvent> {
    public KafkaEvent reduce(KafkaEvent r1, KafkaEvent r2) {
        return r1.getFrequency() > r2.getFrequency() ?
                r2: r1;
    }
}

private static class MyWindowFunction
        implements WindowFunction<KafkaEvent, Tuple2<String, Tuple1<Integer>>, Tuple, TimeWindow> {
    public void apply(Tuple key,
                      TimeWindow window,
                      Iterable<KafkaEvent> minReadings,
                      Collector<Tuple2<String, Tuple1<Integer>>> out) {
        //   Tuple1<Integer> min = minReadings.iterator().next();
        KafkaEvent max = minReadings.iterator().next();
        //out.collect(new Tuple2<Long, SensorReading>(window.getStart(), max));
        out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Tuple1<Integer>>(max.getWord(), new Tuple1(max.getFrequency())));
    }
}



public class KafkaEvent {

    private String word;
    private int frequency;
    private long timestamp;
}
```

What I got:

```
(?? t word1111,(1))
(?? t word1111,(11))
```

What I expected:

```
(?? t word1111,(1))
```

Test data for the KAFKA:

```
    String word = "word1111";
    result = kafkaProducerClientUsage1.sendStringMessageWithByteArray(word, 9);
    result = kafkaProducerClientUsage1.sendStringMessageWithByteArray(word, 5);
    result = kafkaProducerClientUsage1.sendStringMessageWithByteArray(word, 11);
    result = kafkaProducerClientUsage1.sendStringMessageWithByteArray(word, 8);
    result = kafkaProducerClientUsage1.sendStringMessageWithByteArray(word, 1);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code, you've used? Did you really got those results with `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` or have you used `TumblingEventTimeWindows`. With the latter your results are quite understandable. With `ProcessingTime` in general the results may be nondeterministic, but the results that you've posted would be quite strange with that window.

Comment: I used both TumblingProcessingTimeWindows and TumblingEventTimeWindows to do the test, and both of them got the same results. my puzzles are : I used the ReduceFunction to get the event with smallest field Frequency ,why return two events? shouldn't them just return single event with smallest Frequency? Also why "With the latter your results are quite understandable. With ProcessingTime in general the results may be nondeterministic" ,can you kindly give more detail explanation?

Comment: `Reduce` function when applied to window stream is applied to each window separately. Therefore, in EventTime, there will be two results cause there will be two windows of size 10 seconds. (event with timestamp 11) starts another one. In ProcessingTime it is nondeterministic cause you never know for sure when the event will be processed (what timestamp will it have, and which window will it be assigned to).